# Disable email forwarding by for our recipients

Tags: email, email-forwarding

We send out some newsletters and other information of upcoming events etc. to our customers.

What's happening is some of our customers are forwarding out our emails to our competitors.

I couldn't find much info available on how to prevent them to forward the emails.

I found a service called Virtru that can disable forwarding but our emails are sent from code automatically and not manually.

Are the any good solutions available?

Comment: Once the mail is in their Inbox you can't prevent them from doing anything with it.

Comment: True and even after disabling forward (if any solution exists) I know they can still copy the contents or take a screen-shot etc.

Comment: Sounds like you have some real dodgy customers, you're only real option is to get them sign an NDA. Whether that works out so well in practice is another matter.

Comment: Obviously I meant *your*, I've had a drink or two this evening. ;)